# Specific Column Dump from Parquet File using Parquet-tools.jar

Tags: hadoop, parquet

I want to dump only a specific column on some text file using parquet-tools-1.8.1.jar.But not able to do so. I am trying below command. Please note my column name has forward slash.

```
parquet-tools-1.8.1.jar dump --column 'dir1/log1/job12121' '/hdfs-path/to/parquet file with space.parquet' > /home/local/parquet/output.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
hadoop jar parquet-tools-1.8.1.jar parquet.tools.Main dump --column 'dir1/log1/job12121' '/hdfs-path/to/parquet file with space.parquet' > /home/local/parquet/output.text
```

Comment: Radim, i tried command mentioned by you it says Unknown command: parquet.tools.Main

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following:

hadoop jar parquet-tools-1.8.1.jar dump -c dir1 log1 job12121 -m /hdfs-path/to/parquet file with space.parquet >> /home/local/parquet/output.text

Note:No single quotes for input arguments.